# Basic JSON parsing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm very new to this, so could someone provide a really basic example?

Let's say the file located at http://www.example.org/test.json is this:

```
{
   "test":{
      "example":"Test",
      "another":"Text"
   },
   "blah":123
}
```

and the HTML is this:

```
<div id="whatever"></div>
```

How would I extract "Test" from the file and `.append` it in `#whatever` using jQuery?

Comment: The jQuery documentation is pretty reasonable. Which bit of the process is giving you problems?

Comment: I suggest you check the documentation on getJSON for Jquery here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.org/test.json', function(data) {
  $('#whatever').append(data.test.example);
});
```